# nginx+fcgiwrap error "fastcgi request record is too big"

Tags: nginx, github, limit, fastcgi, webhooks

I have auto-deployment bash script, that is called by github webhook thru nginx+fcgiwrap for any push events. But when payload of github webhook POST request is bigger then 64kb, I get the following error in in nginx error.log and script is not called

> **fastcgi request record is too big**

Below is nginx location block for this webhook:

```
location /deploy {
    gzip off;
    client_body_buffer_size 1M;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT /var/www;
    fastcgi_param REQUEST_BODY $request_body;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/deploy.sh;
}
```

Is there any way to increase this limit? Or may there is another way to pass request body to script and run it?

Answer (score 2):

The issue was resolved by using  the following workaround:

```
        location /deploy {
           gzip off;
           client_body_in_file_only clean;
           client_body_temp_path /var/tmp;
           fastcgi_pass_request_body off;
           include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
           fastcgi_param REQUEST_BODY_FILE $request_body_file;
           fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/deploy.sh;
           fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket;
        }
```

In this case we pass the request body to script thru temporary file and disable direct passing to avoid the above error.